# Не видит scss модуль

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scss, react-router, vite

При добавлении компонента Registration в роут '/auth/*' он перестаёт читать/видеть стили из своего модуля. Хотя если достать его из '/auth/*' то начинает видеть стили обратно.
В чём может быть трабл?

```
import { Registration } from '@components/registration/registration';
import { ErrorUserExist } from '@components/result/error-user-exist/error-user-exist';
import { Error } from '@components/result/error/error';
import { Success } from '@components/result/success/success';
import { ErrorsPage } from '@pages/errors-page/errors';
import { MainPage } from '@pages/main-page';
import { RegistrationPage } from '@pages/registration-page';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

export const routes = (
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/main' element={<MainPage />} />
        <Route path='/auth/*' element={<RegistrationPage />}>
            <Route index element={<>auth</>} />
            <Route path='registration' element={<Registration />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='result/*' element={<ErrorsPage />}>
            <Route path='success' element={<Success />} />
            <Route path='error' element={<Error />} />
            <Route path='error-user-exist' element={<ErrorUserExist />} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
);

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { registrationRequest } from '../../API/registration-request';
import s from './registration.module.scss';



export const Registration: React.FC = () => {код компонента...}

import { Layout } from 'antd';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import s from './registration-page.module.scss';

export const RegistrationPage: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Layout className={s.container__registration}>
            <Outlet />
        </Layout>
    );
};
```